# How to uninstall Ubuntu installed through the windows installer

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 today using windows installer as I was using Windows 7 on My Dell Inspiron 1545 model.

It installed successfully but I can not connect to Wi Fi Network though it works perfectly fine on my Windows 7.

I tried to troubleshoot and install the drivers , but could not.

I want to uninstall Ubuntu now and reclaim my 15GB C space.

How should I do it now?

Comment: By windows installer you mean [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ubuntu using ***Wubi*** then there will be an application in the folder where you installed Ubuntu with the name : uninstall-ubuntu. Run it to uninstall.

If you installed ubuntu ***permanantly*** then

- open Windows
- format the 15 GB partition
- Reboot with Windows installer CD
- Search for Repair Windows option and look for Grub Rescue or Boot Rescue or similar option.

Just make sure you have the Windows Installation CD with you **before** starting or its going to get messy.

Comment: I tried to uninstall using following link:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUgf84bdYvg

Now when I go to disk management I can see only NTFS partitions only. But when I restart my PC I find both Ubuntu and windows 7 options and I can log into Ubuntu as well.

I tried searching for uninstall-ubuntu file but can not find it on my laptop.

I need to install Ubuntu permanently . So if I make a bootable UBUNTU 12.10 pen drive and try to install , will I get rid of this Wubi Ubuntu version ?

Comment: I also tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on but again stuck at disk management as I can not see the Ubuntu partition

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu 12.10 permanently, go to disk manager and clear (shrink) 15GB of hard disk space from any drive (recommended 18GB, but you can vary). Make sure that it is 'Free' or 'Un-allocated'. Then just use LiveCD or LiveUSB to install Ubuntu. It will automatically capture the free memory.

Before installing it, just locate the existing Ubuntu installation folder and delete it. Remember that in your existing way of installation there is no separate drive for Ubuntu, but rather a partition inside a partition, which won't show up in Disk Manager. Just check C drive for a folder named Ubuntu (it'll be immediately inside the drive and not in any sub-folder i.e. `C:\Ubuntu-something` ) and delete it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.